# Computing Log-likelihood Model Manually for Logit Model

Tags: r, logistic, likelihood

A log-likelihood function takes on the form of: logL$=\Sigma^{n}_{i=1}(y_ilog(\frac{e^{\beta' x_i}}{1+e^{\beta'x_i}} )+(1-y_i)(\frac{e^{\beta' x_i}}{1+e^{\beta'x_i}})$

My logit model is estimated as follows:

```
glm.logit=glm(model,binomial(),data)
```

Estimating $y_i$

```
yi=data$y
```

x's as a matrix of the dependent variable

```
 xi=cbind(data$x1+data$x2+...)
```

Taking the estimates of $\beta$ from my model

```
betai=coef(glm.logit)
```

Putting the these together:

```
xibetai<-xi%*%t(betai)
```

Estimating the logistic form:

```
logiti<-exp(xibetai)/(1+exp(xibetai))
```

Putting everything together in the form of a log-likelihood model:

```
LogLi<-yi%*%log(logiti)+(1-yi)%*%log(1-logiti)
```

Issue with the fact that you can't take take the log of a negative value, so I only get about half of my coefficients in the output.

Comment: The default link function for the binomial family is logit.  It looks like you want log.  Try binomial("log") as the family.

Comment: what exactly do you want to do? Extract the predicted probabilities for each observation? Extract the log-likelihood for the model? Compute the log-likelihood for the model manually? (see `?predict`, `?logLik` ...) This might be more appropriate for StackOverflow, as it looks more like "how do I compute ... ?" rather than "what should I compute?" or "what does this mean?"

Comment: @BenBolker I want to compute the log-likelihood model manually without using logLik. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Both your log-likelihood equation and your R code have some errors:

$$
\begin{split}
\eta_i & = \mathbf{X}_i \boldsymbol{\beta} \quad \textrm{(so far so good)} \\
p_i & = \exp(\eta_i)/(1+\exp(\eta_i)) = 1/(1+\exp(-\eta_i)) \\
L_i & = y_i \log p_i + (1-y) \log(1-p_i) \\
L & = \sum L_i
\end{split}
$$

In R you can use `plogis()` for the logistic ($1/(1+\exp(-\eta_i))$):

```r
p <- plogis(X %*% beta)
sum(y*log(p) + (1-y)*log(1-p))
```

(or `dbinom(y, prob=p, size=1, log=TRUE)`)

If your coefficients include an intercept, $\mathbf{X}$ should include a column of 1s at the corresponding position (usually the first column). You can check various intermediate results with `predict(fitted_model, type="link")` ($\eta$), `predict(fitted_model, type="response")` ($p$).

Comment: Thanks for your response, I had a couple of errors in my log-likelihood function, I have corrected these, my output and your output both give the same answer, however, this answer is incorrect. I suspect that the way I have multiplied x and beta may be wrong as beta includes the intercept.

Comment: Thanks again, I'm slightly confused over how to use predict(), does it give me as output, my x variables multiplied by my betas? Thanks

Comment: yes,  if you specify `type="link"` (the default)